# Excluding PO Box Addresses using the pattern attribute

Tags: regex, forms, validation, input

First off I'm aware that there are already a few threads on here regarding excluding PO Box addresses but it seems that the majority of them use Jquery and my attempts to replicate them within my platform (prestashop) haven't worked out for me. While this may be the solution I resort to if all else fails I'm hoping to use the pattern input attribute if it's possible.

I've got a regular expression that I wish to use within the pattern attribute however I'm not too familiar with regular expressions. In fact I've only recently come across them.

I'm looking to validate a form based on whether a PO Box address has been inputted. If it has then the form will not submit. After doing some research I've come across the following expression which is said to do what I'm looking for:

```
^ *((#\d+)|((box|bin)[-. \/\\]?\d+)|(.*p[ \.]? ?(o|0)[-. \/\\]? *-?((box|bin)|b|(#|num)?\d+))|(p(ost)? *(o(ff(ice)?)?)? *((box|bin)|b)? *\d+)|(p *-?\/?(o)? *-?box)|post office (box|bin)|((box|bin)|b) *(number|num|#)? *\d+|(num|number|#) *\d+)
```

This expression is far too complex for my understanding but looking at it in Regex101 it seems to be doing the opposite of what I'm looking for, I could be misunderstanding but it seems to be validating PO boxes and excluding everything else. Regardless of that I tried it on my form but it seems to make it so that regardless of what is inputted it wont be excepted.

This has lead me to believe that either I've done something wrong or the pattern input field doesn't support such complex expressions or it needs to be in a different syntax if it does.

I'd appreciate some clarification on that matter and recommended steps to take in validating my forms.

**Does the pattern input attribute support this type of expression and if not how should I go about validating my forms with it?**

***And for clarification does this expression validate PO boxes or exclude them and if it validates them how would I go about changing it to do the opposite?***

Here is the code I'm currently using:

```
<label for="return-street-address">Street Address <span class="asterisk">*</span></label> <input type="text" value="" name="ADDRESS" required id="return-street-address" "^(?! *(#\d+|(box|bin)[-. /\\]?\d+|.*p[ .]? ?[o0][-. /\\]? *-?((box|bin)|b|(#|num)?\d+)|p(ost)? *(o(ff(ice)?)?)? *((box|bin)|b)? *\d+|p *-?/?o? *-?box|post office (box|bin)|((box|bin)|b) *(number|num|#)? *\d+|(num|number|#) *\d+)).*">
```

These:

```
PO Box 123
P.O. BOX 123
```

should not get validated with this code.

Comment: That means you need something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/g2DXcv/1)?

Comment: Thanks Wiktor but there doesn't seem to be anything there.

Comment: Re-click the link to see `^(?! *(#\d+|(box|bin)[-. /\\]?\d+|.*p[ .]? ?[o0][-. /\\]? *-?((box|bin)|b|(#|num)?\d+)|p(ost)? *(o(ff(ice)?)?)? *((box|bin)|b)? *\d+|p *-?/?o? *-?box|post office (box|bin)|((box|bin)|b) *(number|num|#)? *\d+|(num|number|#) *\d+)).*` demo. Also, see https://jsfiddle.net/nfw3ogy2/.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work unfortunately, now it's seems to just let both addresses and PO Boxes validate.

Comment: Please share your code, and provide examples you test against.

Comment: No, please remove this comment and add the code to the question body as a snippet.

Comment: My apologies, I'm a bit of a novice using this site. The comment has been deleted and amended to the original question.

Comment: Ok, I see you did not copy/paste my regex correctly, and thus did not even test *my* regex.

Comment: Another point: you seem to want a case insensitive pattern, but there is no way to pass a   modifier in an HTML5 pattern attribute.

Comment: I did test _yours_. I copied it directly from your js fiddle. I've now tested it in both my code and in regex101 and it validates all three of my examples when it should only validate the non PO Box entry.

Comment: Ok, I will leave you with https://jsfiddle.net/tLag1790/1/

Comment: That looks to have worked. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the pattern you found, you need to remove unnecessary escapes inside character classes, and replace each letter with a character class including the lower- and uppercase variant of the letter (it is necessary since one cannot pass a regex modifier with an HTML5 pattern).

Use

```css
input:valid {
  color: black;
}
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<label for="return-street-address">Street Address <span class="asterisk">*</span></label> <input type="text" value="" name="ADDRESS" required id="return-street-address" pattern="^(?! *(#\d+|([bB][oO][Xx]|[Bb][Ii][Nn])[-. /\\]?\d+|.*[pP][ .]? ?[Oo0][-. /\\]? *-?(([bB][oO][Xx]|[Bb][Ii][Nn])|b|(#|[Nn][Uu][Mm])?\d+)|[Pp]([Oo][Ss][Tt])? *([Oo]([Ff]{2}([Ii][Cc][Ee])?)?)? *(([bB][oO][Xx]|[Bb][Ii][Nn])|b)? *\d+|[Pp] *-?/?[Oo]? *-?[bB][oO][Xx]|[Pp][Oo][Ss][Tt] [Oo][Ff][Ff][Ii][Cc][Ee] ([bB][oO][Xx]|[Bb][Ii][Nn])|(([bB][oO][Xx]|[Bb][Ii][Nn])|[Bb]) *([Nn][Uu][Mm][Bb][Ee][Rr]|[Nn][Uu][Mm]|#)? *\d+|([Nn][Uu][Mm][Bb][Ee][Rr]|[Nn][Uu][Mm]|#) *\d+)).*">
```