# Combine HTML 5 input pattern for PO Box and address special character disallowance

Tags: javascript, html, regex, reactjs

I have two separate regular expression patterns for an HTML 5 input field for addresses.

The first doesn't allow special characters and a character range I'd like to apply and works on its own:

```
pattern="[-.0-9A-zÀ-ž ]+"
```

The second doesn't allow the input of PO Boxes and also works on its own:

```
pattern="^(?! *(#\d+|([bB][oO][Xx]|[Bb][Ii][Nn])[-. /\\]?\d+|.*[pP][ .]? ?[Oo0][-. /\\]? *-?(([bB][oO][Xx]|[Bb][Ii][Nn])|b|(#|[Nn][Uu][Mm])?\d+)|[Pp]([Oo][Ss][Tt])? *([Oo]([Ff]{2}([Ii][Cc][Ee])?)?)? *(([bB][oO][Xx]|[Bb][Ii][Nn])|b)? *\d+|[Pp] *-?/?[Oo]? *-?[bB][oO][Xx]|[Pp][Oo][Ss][Tt] [Oo][Ff][Ff][Ii][Cc][Ee] ([bB][oO][Xx]|[Bb][Ii][Nn])|(([bB][oO][Xx]|[Bb][Ii][Nn])|[Bb]) *([Nn][Uu][Mm][Bb][Ee][Rr]|[Nn][Uu][Mm]|#)? *\d+|([Nn][Uu][Mm][Bb][Ee][Rr]|[Nn][Uu][Mm]|#) *\d+)).*"
```

There are two problems, though.

**Problem 1:** I can't seem to figure out how to combine the two patterns into one, because in some cases I need to disallow PO Boxes for certain clients (long story).

**Problem 2:** This is a React application and even deciding on what pattern to use requires a JS check. Unfortunately it seems that if I try to apply the pattern to a JS variable and then apply it to the input field, its stripping some characters and no longer working.

For instance:

```
const poBoxPattern = !includes(PO_BOX_ALLOWED, companyId)
    ? '^(?! *(#\d+|([bB][oO][Xx]|[Bb][Ii][Nn])[-. /\\]?\d+|.*[pP][ .]? ?[Oo0][-. /\\]? *-?(([bB][oO][Xx]|[Bb][Ii][Nn])|b|(#|[Nn][Uu][Mm])?\d+)|[Pp]([Oo][Ss][Tt])? *([Oo]([Ff]{2}([Ii][Cc][Ee])?)?)? *(([bB][oO][Xx]|[Bb][Ii][Nn])|b)? *\d+|[Pp] *-?/?[Oo]? *-?[bB][oO][Xx]|[Pp][Oo][Ss][Tt] [Oo][Ff][Ff][Ii][Cc][Ee] ([bB][oO][Xx]|[Bb][Ii][Nn])|(([bB][oO][Xx]|[Bb][Ii][Nn])|[Bb]) *([Nn][Uu][Mm][Bb][Ee][Rr]|[Nn][Uu][Mm]|#)? *\d+|([Nn][Uu][Mm][Bb][Ee][Rr]|[Nn][Uu][Mm]|#) *\d+)).*'
    : '[-.0-9A-zÀ-ž ]+';
```

Note that the code is just using either or pattern (since I don't know how to combine the two in the first statement, but even that is breaking down. I see the following error in Chrome:

> Pattern attribute value ^(?! *(#d+|([bB][oO][Xx]|[Bb][Ii][Nn])[-. /]?d+|.*[pP][ .]? ?[Oo0][-. /]? *-?(([bB][oO][Xx]|[Bb][Ii][Nn])|b|(#|[Nn][Uu][Mm])?d+)|Pp? *(Oo?)? *(([bB][oO][Xx]|[Bb][Ii][Nn])|b)? *d+|[Pp] *-?/?[Oo]? *-?[bB][oO][Xx]|[Pp][Oo][Ss][Tt] [Oo][Ff][Ff][Ii][Cc][Ee] ([bB][oO][Xx]|[Bb][Ii][Nn])|(([bB][oO][Xx]|[Bb][Ii][Nn])|[Bb]) *([Nn][Uu][Mm][Bb][Ee][Rr]|[Nn][Uu][Mm]|#)? *d+|([Nn][Uu][Mm][Bb][Ee][Rr]|[Nn][Uu][Mm]|#) *d+)).* is not a valid regular expression: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^(?! *(#d+|([bB][oO][Xx]|[Bb][Ii][Nn])[-. /]?d+|.*[pP][ .]? ?[Oo0][-. /]? *-?(([bB][oO][Xx]|[Bb][Ii][Nn])|b|(#|[Nn][Uu][Mm])?d+)|Pp? *(Oo?)? *(([bB][oO][Xx]|[Bb][Ii][Nn])|b)? *d+|[Pp] *-?/?[Oo]? *-?[bB][oO][Xx]|[Pp][Oo][Ss][Tt] [Oo][Ff][Ff][Ii][Cc][Ee] ([bB][oO][Xx]|[Bb][Ii][Nn])|(([bB][oO][Xx]|[Bb][Ii][Nn])|[Bb]) *([Nn][Uu][Mm][Bb][Ee][Rr]|[Nn][Uu][Mm]|#)? *d+|([Nn][Uu][Mm][Bb][Ee][Rr]|[Nn][Uu][Mm]|#) *d+)).*/: Unmatched ')'

Could really use some help here as I'm terrible with regular expressions and a bit puzzled on this one.

Comment: For starter, you seams to have syntax error in your pattern. Try to use https://regex101.com/ to fix those first.

Comment: And you can ignore case or convert case and just check against words. And if you have differing validation requirements then why would you want to combine them?

Comment: @Nicolas the pattern is valid, I pulled it from here and it works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41100531/excluding-po-box-addresses-using-the-pattern-attribute

Comment: @DaveNewton Because one needs to support both and the other only one.

Comment: @reintroducing That doesn’t answer the question. You have two requirements, there’s zero reason to combine them, especially with the monster of regex you’ve created.

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm not really sure why you think there is zero reason to combine them. The pattern should support both of those limitations, as in not allowing a PO Box and not allowing special characters. I didn't create the regexp for the PO Box, i pulled it from the SO I found which I linked to in my reply to Nicolas. What exactly am I not answering? I thought I provided all the details in my original question but what would you like clarification on? I'd be happy to provide it if it will help you answer the question directly.

Comment: You explicitly said you have two requirements that are not always used at the same time. This makes combining regexes pointless—just check whichever ones are relevant and keep them separate and distinct. You explicitly said you’re not good with regexes, which is clear, so why make your regexes even *more * difficult to manage, test, and modify?

Comment: @DaveNewton "Problem 1: I can't seem to figure out how to combine the two patterns into one, because in some cases I need to disallow PO Boxes for certain clients (long story)." I explicitly said I need to combine them. That being said, its apparent that you're not trying to actually help rather just beat a dead horse, and SO is warning me about not getting into long discussions in comments, so I'll wait for someone who can offer a bit more insight here to answer my question. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You don’t need to combine them, you need to validate against two separate things. There’s no reason it needs to be in a single regex—and it shouldn’t be, especially with the way the regex is currently written (which is a completely separate, and ultimately more important, issue). Ignore the advice all you want.

Comment: @DaveNewton Its clear that I don't know how to properly solve this, so rather than telling me everything that is wrong, it would be much appreciated if you proposed a spelled out solution on how to do this correctly with code samples.

Comment: First, regex tutorial (seriously; they’re incredibly useful). Second: change approach—just down-case the input and skip all the case-insensitive stuff. Third: it’s React, you have dynamic validation requirements, just do the validations in JS, whichever are appropriate for a given client. There are a *lot* of ways to handle valuations in JS and React—which makes the most sense is largely opinion-based.